# Mysql сортировка по полю другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть такой запрос.

```
Select * from `f_list` where `id_receiver` = 'id' or `id_sender` = 'id'
```

Решил сделать сортировку по полю из другой таблицы в которой хранится таймстамп когда пользователь в последний раз посещал сайт что то типа

```
Select *
From `f_list`
Inner join `users` as `last_visit`
Where `id_sender` = 'id' or `id_receiver` = 'id'
Order by `last_visit` desc
```

Все как бы вроде работает но должно выводится 8 записей а по итогу выводит эти 8 дважды и во второй раз уже в разнобой.

Comment: ```Where `id_sender` = 'id' or `id_receiver` = 'id'``` Косяк. Какой смысл сравнивать значение поля (в котором идентификатор, скорее всего числовой) со строковым литералом `'id'`? И где условие связывания? и почему не указаны алиасы таблиц у полей?

Comment: Воу по медленее я даже не знаю что такое алиасы и что за связывание, а по поводу сравнений строки и числа строка автоматически подгонится под тип с которым идет сравнение

Comment: *по поводу сравнений строки и числа строка автоматически подгонится под тип с которым идет сравнение* Строка `'id'` будет преобразована в ноль. Тогда уж сразу пиши ```Where `id_sender` = 0 or `id_receiver` = 0```, чего сервер лишней работой нагружать...

Comment: У меня все запросы построенны так и все работает как надо в ноль ничего не преобразуется

Comment: *все работает как надо в ноль ничего не преобразуется* Значит, тут фигню написали. В MySQL каждый тип кавычек выполняет свои, строго описанные, функции, и лепить какие под руку подвернулись - ошибка. Исправьте текст вопроса и проставьте везде правильные кавычки, чтобы появился смысл.

Comment: Если это у меня так работает то почему фигня, фигня если бы не работало было бы